# How to get jQuery to work with Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get jQuery to work with Laravel 5.4. I installed jQuery with npm. I have two files in the same folder: `app.js` and `bootstrap.js`. From `app.js` I import the file `bootstrap.js` with:

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

In `bootstrap.js` I import jQuery with:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Still in my blade view when I try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('jQuery is working!');
    });
</script>
```

I get a reference error telling me that "$ is not defined".

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include it in your view? You need to put in something like this:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Yes! But I had the `async` attribute set to `async` in my `script` tag. Solved it!